# Filter the txt file satisfies some condition in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file contained the *subjectid_num_[dog/cat]_[option]*.

```
ID1_0123_CAT_ANIMAL_3
ID1_0123_CAT_ANIMAL_GOOD_3
ID1_0123_ABC_3
ID2_1234_CAT_ANIMAL_3
ID2_1234_CAT_ANIMAL_GOOD_3
ID2_1234_DOG_ANIMAL_2
ID2_1234_DOG_ANIMAL_GOOD_0
ID2_1234_ABCD_3
ID3_4321_DOG_ANIMAL_1
ID3_4321_DOG_ANIMAL_GOOD_4
ID3_4321_DOG_3
```

I want to filter the file to get the output that satisfies the condition. For example, the below code will file the output has `CAT` and `GOOD` in the name, **and does not** contains the `DOG` and `GOOD` in the name. The name is determined by same `subject_id` and same number `num`. However, the code does not show my expected output. How should I fix it?

This is my code

```
with open("./cat_dog.txt", 'r') as f:
    files_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
file_filter = []
for i, cat in enumerate(files_list):
    if 'GOOD' in cat and 'CAT' in cat:
        subject_id = cat.split('_')[0]
        num_id = cat.split('_')[1]
        subject_num = subject_id + '_' + num_id
        for j, dog in enumerate(files_list):
                if subject_num in dog and 'GOOD' in dog:
                    if 'GOOD' in dog and 'DOG' in dog:
                        continue;
                    else:
                        file_filter.append(cat)
```

The current output is

```
ID1_0123_CAT_ANIMAL_GOOD_3
ID2_1234_CAT_ANIMAL_GOOD_3
```

While the expected is

```
ID1_0123_CAT_ANIMAL_GOOD_3
```

Comment: Both the item listed in current output are a match, so why should you only get one?

Comment: Because the second one contains the good and dog

Comment: Where's dog in this string? - ID2_1234_CAT_ANIMAL_GOOD_3

Comment: `ID2_1234_DOG_ANIMAL_GOOD_0` because it same the name `ID2_1234`

Comment: That details wasn't clear in your question.  I'm looking at the issue now.

Comment: I think you did not read the question carefully "the below code will file the output has CAT and GOOD in the name, and does not contains the DOG and GOOD in the name. The name is determined by same subject_id and same number num"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Consider what happens when you check line `ID2_1234_CAT_ANIMAL_GOOD_3` in the inner loop:

```
subject_id = cat.split('_')[0]            #ID2
num_id = cat.split('_')[1]                # 1234
subject_num = subject_id + '_' + num_id   #ID2_1234
for j, dog in enumerate(files_list):
        # when dog is the line ID2_1234_CAT_ANIMAL_GOOD_3
        if subject_num in dog and 'GOOD' in dog:   # this is true
            if 'GOOD' in dog and 'DOG' in dog:   # this is false
                continue;
            else:
                file_filter.append(cat)   # then it outputs it
```

The problem is that every line with `GOOD` and `CAT` in it will "match itself" in the inner loop.

IMHO I'd use `itertools.groupby`. Something along the lines of:

```
from itertools import groupby

def key(line):
    return line.split('_')[:2]

for key, lines in groupby(sorted(files_list, key=key), key=key):
    good_lines = [line for line in lines if 'GOOD' in line]
    if len(good_lines) == 1 and 'CAT' in good_lines[0]:
        file_filter.append(good_lines[0])
```

This should also be more efficient O(nlog n) vs O(n^2), although it needs all the contents of the file in RAM.

---

If you have other "classes" other than `CAT` and `DOG` and you want to output all `GOOD CAT` lines except if the `subject_id` is also a `GOOD` `DOG` you can modify the code above in this way:

```
is_good_cat = any('CAT' in line for line in good_lines)
is_good_dog = any('DOG' in line for line in good_lines)
if is_good_cat and not is_good_dog:
    file_filter.extend(line for line in good_lines if 'CAT' in good_lines)
```

(You need to use `.extend` and the loop because we no longer know which is the line to write, so you have to filter them.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Just change `file_filter.append(good_lines[0])`

Comment: @John Oh yes, for some reason I was thinking of a file. Anyway I suggest you take the time to try `itertools.groupby` and the module in general. It is really helpful as a module.

Comment: Thanks. But I have a question, why only compare with `'CAT' in good_lines[0]`. What happend if the `CAT` in other position of `good_lines`

Comment: @John There is the condition `len(good_lines) == 1` so you know that `good_lines` contains exactly one element. Now if your input can contain the same subject_id with good cat in multiple lines then yes you have to change that, but how depends on specifically how you want to handle that case.

Comment: Thanks for your information. If my output for each good_lines will be `['ID1_1234_ABC_DSF_GOOD_1', 'ID1_1234_CAT_GOOD_5', 'ID1_1234_DOG_GOOD_4', 'ID1_1234_HGF_GOOD_3']
['ID2_1234_ABC_DSF_GOOD_1', 'ID2_1234_CAT_GOOD_5']`. How to get the `ID1_1234_CAT_GOOD_5` in the second one

Comment: @John I updated the answer with a possible solution.